# Metapost - How to obtain the coordinates of a given point?

Tags: metapost

Given an arbitrary point, let's say p, that may or may not be obtained by several indirect processes such as penpos or by intersections, how do I get to display the coordinates "(px,py)" of the point in the pdf generated ? when I don't have those coordinates to beguin with ?   I remember having done this once already, but I forgot how to do it.

Comment: Try `z1 = p;` Then `x1` and `y1` will hold the values you are looking for. You can use a label to display them in the PDF.

Comment: That doesn't do it for me, I really need the value of the coordinates of the point, not just to use the point.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in my code:

Comment: z23=(-1.272cm,-3.053cm);
z24=(-1.12cm,-2.148cm);
z25=(-1.2405cm,-1.6084cm);
z3=(-1.072cm,0cm);
z27=(-1.011cm,0.468cm);
z26=(-1.296cm,-0.331cm);
penpos23(0.25cm,70.2567+90);
penpos24(0.7cm,-87.3949-90);
penpos25(0.8cm,-66.3078-90);
penpos26(1.07cm,77.13501+90);
penpos3(1.24cm,21.801);
penpos27(1.1294cm,64.09569+78);



z111=(precontrol 5 of (z23l..z24l..z25l..z3r--z27..z26..z25..z24..z23--cycle));

label.bot(TEX decimal(x111) ,(10,20));

Comment: In the log it says that there is a `,' missing.

Comment: It's hard to debug something without a code example (MWE) which would help us help you. Maybe you could add one?

Comment: You want `xpart p` and `ypart p`

Answer (score 2):

Given a pair `p`, the two values are available as `xpart p` and `ypart p`.

To make a string representation of the pair try:

```
"(" & decimal xpart p & "," & decimal ypart p & ")"
```

You can then type set that string as usual with `infont` or the `TEX()` macro.

```
 label.bot(TEX("$(" & decimal xpart p & "," & decimal ypart p & ")$"), (10, 20));
```

This is rather less cumbersome if you use the built-in plain shorthand notation for pairs.  So given a pair variable `z1`, the two values are available as `x1` and `y1`.  And you can make a string representation as

```
 "(" & decimal x1 & "," & decimal y1 & ")"
```